# Null pointer Exception while getting contacts List through TableLayout

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get contact detail and images through table layout and I got null pointer exception at for loop. Any suggestion will be appreciated...

Code is here below...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData> tmpList;
    TableLayout tableLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.categoriesTable);

        getContacts(MainActivity.this,"");

        populateTable();

    }

    public void populateTable() {

        tableLayout.removeAllViews();

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpList.size(); i++) {
            final TableRow row = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams rowLayout = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            rowLayout.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 5);
            row.setLayoutParams(rowLayout);

            row.setId(i);
            row.setClickable(true);

            RelativeLayout parentLayout = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);

            RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);
            relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color.black);
            relativeLayout.setId(8);

//            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams childLayout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//            parentLayout.addView(relativeLayout, childLayout);

            TextView nameTV = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            nameTV.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD);
            nameTV.setId(1);
            nameTV.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            nameTV.setTextSize(17);
            nameTV.setSingleLine(true);
            nameTV.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
            nameTV.setText(tmpList.get(i).name);


            final RelativeLayout waveLayout = new RelativeLayout(MainActivity.this);

            waveLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            waveLayout.setId(5);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams waveLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            //waveLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,relativeLayout.getId());
            parentLayout.addView(nameTV, waveLayoutParams);

            row.addView(parentLayout);
            tableLayout.addView(row);
            row.setTag(i);

        }        

    }

    public static ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData> getContacts(Context context,String selection){
          ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData> tmpList = new ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData>();
          String sel=ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" LIKE '%"+selection+"%'";
          Cursor phones = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, sel,null, null);  
          while (phones.moveToNext()) {

              String contactImageName=null;
              String ContactID=null;

              String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
              String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

              contactImageName=getGalleryPic(phoneNumber);
              if(contactImageName==null)
                ContactID = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
              PhoneAddressBookData con = new PhoneAddressBookData(ContactID,name,phoneNumber,contactImageName);
              tmpList.add(con);

          }
          phones.close();

          return tmpList;
    }

    private static String getGalleryPic(String phoneNumber) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line of `getContacts()`:

```
ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData> tmpList = new ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData>();
```

Is creating a new local variable called `tmpList` that is hiding the field `tmpList` that you have defined for the class.

When you use `tmpList` inside `populateTable()`, you are referring to the field, but this will be null because it was never initialised; the code in `getContacts()` is modifying a local object.

To fix this you have 3 options. Either change the line to:

```
tmpList = new ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData>();
```

Or, at the end of `getContacts()` add:

```
this.tmpList = tmpList;
```

Or, since you are returning `tmpList` from that method, change the call to be:

```
tmpList = getContacts(MainActivity.this,"");
```

Comment: tmpList = new ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData>();

It is working now but the phone number are not showing now. . .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the static member `tmpList` is never affected, so in `populateTable()` it is empty, hence calling `size()` on in it returns a NullPointerException.

There are 2 solutions. Either affect  in `onCreate()`:

```
tmpList = getContacts(MainActivity.this,"");
```

Or in `getContacts()`:

```
public static void getContacts(Context context, String selection) {
    tmpList = new ArrayList<PhoneAddressBookData>();
    …
```

where you eventually do not need any return value any more.

Comment: Ok but the phone # are not showing now. It is working for names.